# Changing color scale in a geom_tile

Tags: ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to change the color scale in a geom_tile from a single color to a gradient.
I don't have any error message in my code; 
I had a look at other messages, the cookbook etc there is a lot for a beginner (too much)...

Here is the initial code, which gives a "red gradient" map:

```
`ggplot(pacific.maps,aes(x = long, y = lat),na.rm)+
   geom_polygon(aes(group = group,fill = region),bg = "grey")+
   scale_x_continuous(name="Longitude E", limits=c(100, 180)) +
   scale_y_continuous(name="Latitude S", limits=c(-50, -1))+
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "azure1",colour = "azure1"),
         panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
   geom_tile(data=Y2010,aes(x=LON_F2,y=LAT_F2),alpha=0.1,fill = "red",na.rm=TRUE)`
```

If i try to change these lines below, I get grey tiles :(

```
`geom_tile(data=Y2010,aes(x=LON_F2,y=LAT_F2),alpha=0.1) +
   scale_fill_manual(values=(brewer.pal(3, "RdYlBu")),na.value="white")`
```

I haven't put any data as I think it's most probably a syntax problem (and also because I used the reprex in R studio and that's all what I got!)

I hope this won't take more than a few minutes for experienced people.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `geom_tile()` doesn't seem to have a mapped `fill` aesthetic. Does your problem persists of you use `geom_tile(data = Y2010, aes(x=LON_F2,y=LAT_F2, fill = your_variable), alpha = 0.1)` where `your_variable` is something that you want to map to colour?

Comment: My data is a list of positions of cyclones: each row contains Name / TM / LONG / LAT etc; exemple : Abele  2010-11-29 00:00 -11.40 86.40    I defined LONG_2 and LAT_2 (so 2 new variables)  to have each observation in a new position being a square  of 2x2 degres . For the exemple : LONG_F2 : -12  LAT_F2 :86. And then, I did the plot of LONG_F2 by LAT_F2 where I imagined that it will count the number of observations in each square. (sort of density/surface). So I don't know what to write for "your_variable") Oh dear, I hope you'll understand!

Comment: Alright, so counting the observations in (predefined) 2d bins, and translating that to tiles/rectangels/rasters continuous fill color (gradient)?

Comment: Conceptually, is the following what you want? `ggplot(faithful, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = after_stat(count)),
            stat = "bin_2d")`

Comment: I already have a ggplot with the background map with a long and lat aes. I think I need to have my LAT_F2 and LON_F2  in the aes of the tile to have the proper count. Something like this: geom_tile(data=Y2010,aes(x=LON_F2,y=LAT_F2),fill=after_stat(count),stat="bin_2d"); I guess I have to define the bin_2d ?

Comment: No the `bin_2d` is doing the counting part. Or you might preprocess your data so you already have count information in your `Y2010` dataset, in which case you can give that count variable to `your_variable` in my earliest example.

Comment: New code    geom_tile(data=Y2010,aes(x=LON_F2,y=LAT_F2,fill=after_stat(count)),stat="bin_2d",na.rm=TRUE) +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c('red', 'yellow','blue'))    And it works! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can't see how to close the question

Comment: Does the new code work? You don't need to close the question I think.